# Down-vote and loss of reputations

Tags: discussion

I noticed that, sometimes, when I down vote an answer or a question I lose 1 reputation, but not always, so I wonder:

**Which is the rationale for the loss of 1 reputation after a down-vote**?

Comment: Downvoting question change no rep but downvoting answer will deduct 1 rep from you. Sometime DVted answers get deleted and ur 1 rep will return to you.